# Android: Updating database from viewmodel and unit testing it

Tags: android, junit, viewmodel, coroutine

I have a method in my viewmodel that resets rows in the database.

```
 fun resetScores() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
       for(player in players){ 
           
           player.level = 1
           player.score = 0
           playerDao.updatePlayer(player) // updates the DB
       }
    }
}

var players = mutableListOf<Player>() -- > players is a mutable list
```

I have this unit test for testing this method

```
@Test
fun testResetScores() {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    val viewModel = PlayerViewModel(Phase10DataBase.getDatabase(context).playerDao)
    viewModel.players = mutableListOf(Player(1,"Player1",5,100),
        Player(2,"Player2",5,100),
        Player(3,"Player3",5,100))
    assertEquals(viewModel.players.get(1).score, 100)
    viewModel.resetScores()
    assertEquals(viewModel.players.get(1).score, 100)
}
```

And this test pass whereas I expect it to fail.
Looks like the test is not waiting for the async DB operation to be finished before calling the assert.
What is the right way to test it or should the actual code resetScore need to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Use [runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#bridging-blocking-and-non-blocking-worlds) it blocks until the coroutine is finished

```
@Test
fun testResetScores() = runBlocking {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    val viewModel = PlayerViewModel(Phase10DataBase.getDatabase(context).playerDao)
    viewModel.players = mutableListOf(Player(1,"Player1",5,100),
        Player(2,"Player2",5,100),
        Player(3,"Player3",5,100))
    assertEquals(viewModel.players.get(1).score, 100)
    viewModel.resetScores()
    assertEquals(viewModel.players.get(1).score, 100)
}
```

Comment: that did not fix

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it too late for questioner, but hope this will help anyone else.

This behavior happen because because we create a new coroutine inside `viewModel.resetScores()`, running simultaneously with `assertEquals`, and `assertEqual` being called before we ever make change to `viewModel.players`.

To fix this, we can use [advanceUntilIdle](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/advance-until-idle.html) to wait until all tasks finished:

```
@Test
fun testResetScores() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    val scope: TestScope = TestScope(dispatcher)
    scope.runTest {
        val viewModel = TestViewModel()
        viewModel.players = mutableListOf(
            Player(1, "Player1", 5, 100),
            Player(2, "Player2", 5, 100),
            Player(3, "Player3", 5, 100)
        )
        assertEquals(viewModel.players[1].score, 100)
        viewModel.resetScores()
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(viewModel.players[1].score, 100)
    }
}
```